# What do the CloudFlare CAPTCHA and Challenge pages look like for users?

Tags: captcha, firewall, cloudflare

In the CloudFlare [Web Application Firewall](https://www.cloudflare.com/waf/) you are able to block, whitelist, CAPTCHA, or JavaScript Challenge traffic based on IP address, country name, or ASN. The only note provided on the CAPTCHA section is:

> If you are unsure whether suspicious web visitor behavior is illegitimate traffic, you can set up a challenge page. This page asks visitors to submit a CAPTCHA successfully to continue their action. If the web visitor fails the challenge, they will be blocked from your website.

What do the CAPTCHA and challenge pages looks like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried setting up a challenge for my own IP address and this is what I got:

[image: Cloudflare Firewall Challenge Captcha]

Another test shows sometimes the [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) system is used:

[image: Google reCAPTCHA from CloudFlare]

That appears to be the default challenge page, but if you are using a paid plan there are [options to customize](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172706-How-do-I-customize-CloudFlare-error-pages-) the following error pages:

- IP/Country Block
- WAF Block
- 500 Class Errors
- Enable Origin Error Pages
- 1000 Class Errors
- Always Online™ Error
- Basic Security Challenge
- WAF Challenge
- Country Challenge
- I'm Under Attack Mode™ Challenge

In the firewall section you can also change how often the CAPTCHA will appear (from 5 minutes up to 1 year).

Also it appears that the CAPTCHA response is saved per domain (likely using a cookie), and completing a challenge will allow access to that domain and all sub-domains. Also the challenge page is displayed to the user with a [403 Forbidden response code](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169226-Why-am-I-getting-a-403-error-) which can cause issues with javascript/css if you load those from another domain behind Cloudflare and that domain is included in the challenge with no way to complete the CAPTCHA.

Also I just found out that the CAPTCHA challenge can change for [IPs with higher threat scores or JavaScript/cookies disabled](https://twitter.com/wiretapped/status/583993437042577408):

> @wiretapped The captchas are from Google's reCaptcha. The higher the threat score with the IP = a harder challenge page.

This may or may not occur with IP bans, but here is an example from tor accessing stackoverflow.com with noscript blocking JavaScript:

[image: CloudFlare Tor High Threat CAPTCHA with JavaScript disabled]

Answer (score 10):

Recently CloudFlare added another option to their Firewall section called **JavaScript Challenge**, which will display a loading page with three animated dots for up to 5 seconds:

[image: CloudFlare JavaScript Challenge]

It appears to also use cookies to save the results and allow future access without re-testing.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudflare switched from Google ReCAPTCHA to hcaptcha.

https://www.hcaptcha.com/

https://blog.cloudflare.com/moving-from-recaptcha-to-hcaptcha/

There is a picture of what it looks like at the bottom of the cloudflare blog link.

Answer (score 0):

cloudflare doesnt offer a lot of guidance on best applications for using either of the two options so i used tor to test this, using these instructions from pcauthority.com.au -- since i am trying to block specific countries that are hammering our site:

"The only bit of configuration that’s required is to specify that you want to use exit nodes only in a particular country – otherwise you could end up anywhere in the world.
To do this, go into the Tor Browser\Data\Tor folder and open the configuration file 'torrc' in a text editor such as Notepad.

To use only exit nodes in the US, add these two lines to the end of the configuration file:

StrictExitNodes 1
ExitNodes {US}

If you want to browse from France, enter {FR} instead, and so forth."

my 'challenge' looked similar to the screen snapshot above and the 'js challenge' connected to our site almost seamlessly.

here was the guidance i received from cloudflare tech support: "The javascript challenge is unable to be completed by bots/crawlers as the challenge requires javascript to complete (only browsers can complete this) which means both challenges should work here."

Comment: A VPN like PIA would be very useful for testing from other countries as well.